# Stop redirect/refresh on document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to stop the redirection after a form submition via the document ready function. Ive had a look around and can only find the javascript related `return flase` method (which doesnt work with jquery). Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.document.forms[0].submit();
  });
</script>
```

**NEW Example**

```
<form action="http://example.com/function" name="run">
      <input type="hidden" name="data" value="cheese" />
      <input type="hidden" name="data" value="cheese" />
      <input type="hidden" name="Change" value="Change" />
</form>
<html>
<script>
  $(function(){$('run').submit();});
</script>
<body>
```

**Another Attempt**

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    window.document.forms[0].submit();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Your code submit the form, this is the opposite of what you are looking for. Bind submit event to the form and prevent this behaviour, e.g: `$('form').on('submit', function(){/* use ajax to send data to server */ return false;});`

Comment: I want the code to submit the form, i was looking to sumbit via onload function but it was suggested the document ready function was a better option.

Comment: @iNoob you want to stop the submit or you want to submit it,you can't have them both

Comment: Submiting a form do a reload/redirection. So if you don't want it, bind submit event, prevent default behaviour, and send data to server using ajax

Comment: @A.Wolff could you elaborate with an example code snippet please? The sumbition needs to be silent and none interactive as in the user doesnt click submit the form just submits on its own when the page loads

Answer (score 1):

Use the submit event bind it to your form and use preventDefault to prevent its submision,use ajax to send the data to the server

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({url:url,data:data,success:function(data){//other logic}})
});
```

from what i can tell you want to send data to db when the page is loaded to do that you can use a server side language to do the data saving without using ajax or javascript

Comment: This is the goal, onload submit form via either javascript or jquery but dont redirect page or refresh. So submition should be silent.

Comment: you need ajax for that

Comment: @iNoob And why using a form if it must be on page load, silent and done without any redirection? Why don't you just send data using ajax?

Comment: Cause iNoob @A.Wolff :)

Comment: @iNoob Use this code, and to send data (submit form), use: `$(function(){$('form').submit();});`

Comment: I assume the `'form'` value is the form name? Ive added an example (that doesnt work lol) to the question.

Comment: use `$('form[name="run"]').submit();`

Comment: It still doesnt seem to execure when using `  $(function(){$('form[name="run"]').submit();});`

Comment: "execure" what exacly?

Comment: Apologies on the typo, not executing the form, funnily enough ;) ^_^

Comment: @madalinivascu im not sure how to format the ajax function based on the my form data. Could you please give an example based on my form?

Comment: use `data:$(this).serialize()` this will take all the fields from your form